# Run script in a clean environment

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a script `install.sh`.
I want to put a command at the beginning of this script that will clean the environment for me, keeping only $PATH and $HOME of a parent shell.

I know about `env -i` but it requires **a second script which will do "env -i install.sh"**. I want a single install.sh script which users will run directly ("sh install.sh" or "./install.sh").

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291913/112235 which should work for your case

Comment: @Inian it seems like you have not read the question. "env -i bash --noprofile --norc <command/script.sh>" executes a single command or an external script, but I want to execute the rest of the current script.

Comment: I meant to add that line to the top of your `install.sh` script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [re-exec the script from within it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98846/70524):

```
[ -z "$CLEANED" ] && exec env -i CLEANED=1 "PATH=$PATH" "HOME=$HOME" bash "$0" "$@"
unset CLEANED
```

Where `CLEANED` is a marker variable to tell your script that the environment has been cleaned.

Comment: You've removed a necessary part of the linked answer without which the script will be executed twice, a first time with the clean environment and a second time with the original environment as execution follows past the `exec` command

Comment: @Aaron infinitely many times, actually - it will keep re-execing itself.

Comment: @Aaron thanks a lot, it seems like you have answered my question.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
exec env -i "PATH=$PATH" "HOME=$HOME" bash "$0" "$@"
echo START

never prints START :(

Comment: @ptkvsk it's what Aaron has been talking about - like in the linked post, you need to add a check: `[ -z "$CLEANED" ] && exec env -i CLEANED=1 "PATH=$PATH" "HOME=$HOME" bash "$0" "$@"` - otherwise it will just keep looping.

Comment: Ok, I see... I think it would make sense to move this into the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `compgen -v` to give a list of variable names, and unset each in turn:

```
for i in $(compgen -v)
do
    case "$i" in
      HOME|PATH)
        ;;
      *)
        unset "$i"
        ;;
    esac
done
unset i
```

Note that there are some Bash variables which can't be unset:

- `BASHOPTS`
- `BASH_ARGC`
- `BASH_ARGV`
- `BASH_LINENO`
- `BASH_SOURCE`
- `BASH_VERSINFO`
- `EUID`
- `PIPESTATUS`
- `PPID`
- `SHELLOPTS`
- `UID`
- `_`

Comment: If you try this in an interactive shell, don't be surprised if it appears to hang - it hasn't, but it's hard to tell when you have no `PS1`.